# How fit a point on a ecdf curve

Tags: r, curve-fitting, ecdf

I have a random serie of values, `a <- runif(1000, 0, 10)`, and a single value: `b <- 1.5` . I want to plot the ecdf, and put on it the value to see the probability to have it.

But when i do that:

```
plot(ecdf(a))
points(b, col = 'red', lwd = 2)
```

The points doesn't appear. I think i have to fit the points with the curve to find the y axis value which correspond to it, but i don't really know how to do it. If someoane can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ecdf` returns a function. You can do this:

```
set.seed(42)
a <- runif(1000, 0, 10)
b <- 1.5

e <- ecdf(a)

plot(e)
points(b, e(b), col = 'red', cex= 2)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks! I just don't understand why you used `set.seed` in the beginning of your code?

Comment: To make the random numbers reproducible.